# Dependency Injection With TypeScript

Tags: typescript, web-component, stenciljs

I have the following constructor in my custom web component:

```
import { Component} from '@stencil/core';
import { CartService } from '../../services/cart-service';

@Component({
    tag: 'check-out',
    styleUrl: 'check-out.css'
})
export class CheckOut {

    private cartService: CartService;

    constructor(cartService: CartService) {
        this.cartService = cartService;
    }

    componentDidLoad() {
        this.initialize();
    }

    initialize() {
       ...
    }

    render() {
        return [...];
    }

}
```

Now the problem is whenever I try to build I get the following error:

> src/components/check-out/check-out.tsx:22:17
>              Classes decorated with @Component can not have a "constructor" that takes arguments. All data required by a
>              component must be passed by using class properties decorated with @Prop()
>
> ```
>  L22:      constructor(cartService: CartService) {
>  L23:          this.cartService = cartService;
> ```

My question is how do I inject my service as a dependency into the constructor?
I'm using stenciljs to build the component.

Comment: You don't have the ability to control the Stencil component's constructor due to the same reasons Stencil does not support inheritance: avoiding dynamic analysis of class hierarchies;  making it easier to implement and maintain in library land. You are expected to use properties as specified by the error message. You could use factories and directly h('CheckOut', { cartService: CartService }) to forward the dependency or use a method and forward dependencies at a later time. You could also use some convention and request dependencies at componentDidLoad time from a global dependencies service.

Answer (score 0):

The error say "Classes decorated with @Component can not have a "constructor" that takes arguments" so you can remove @Component or delete constructor params!
I think you Will need the @Components. Let´s try the second option.

**I think this is not correct to do, but its work for me:**

import { Component} from '@stencil/core';

import { CartService } from '../../services/cart-service'; DELETE THIS

export class CheckOut {

```
constructor(cartService: CartService) { DELETE PARAMS

}
```

WHAT I WILL CHANGE IS REPLACE THE IMPORT AND CONSTRUCTOR PARANS TO THIS:

```
    let CartService = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('cart-service'));
this.cartService = CartService.CartService;
```

Now initialize:

```
initialize() {
   ...
  let CartService = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('cart- 
   service'));
   this.cartService = CartService.CartService;
}
```

this can be userful:

[Use Methods](https://stenciljs.com/docs/methods)

[Using Variables](https://stenciljs.com/docs/properties)